# Can I Stop a javaexec Failure Killing a Gradle Task?

Tags: multithreading, gradle, geb

I've got a gradle task iterating over a file tree and making a javaexec call on each matched file:

```
task runFeatures {
    doLast {
        fileTree(dir: 'src/test/resources/features', include:'**/*.feature').each { file ->
            javaexec {
                main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
                classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
                args = [
                   ...
                   '--plugin', json:build/reports/cucumber/${file.filename}",
                   ...
                   file.absolutePath
                ]
            }
            generateReportFromJson()
        }
    }
```

The reason for doing this is to run cucumber/geb tests concurrently using GPars.

Being calls to cucumber, it's expected that these javaexecs will return errors, and it's just as obvious that a test framework needs to respond to errors rather than dying on the spot.

But as far as I can tell, as soon as a feature file returns an error code from a  javaexec, gradle immediately terminates the whole task (i.e. the whole test run in this case) rather than giving the task options about how it responds to a failure.

In this case `generateReportFromJson()` never gets called if there's a single scenario failing.

There's a post [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/capturing-and-handling-non-zero-javaexec-result-code/5993) where the author writes a patch for javaexec to solve this issue. This was back in 2012 but I can't find the end of that story, if there is one.

So the only way round it that I can see is to call a gradle subtask from within a shell and have the subtask perform an autoexec [like this](https://github.com/camiloribeiro/cucumber-gradle-parallel/blob/master/build.gradle). But this seems clunky to say the least, especially as my code needs to run on both Linux and Windows.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can configure the javaexec not causing your build to fail by using the `ignoreExitValue`  property:

```
javaexec {
    ...
    ignoreExitValue = true
}
```

Comment: This got me on the right track. It seems there is (or is now) an exception you can handle in this case-- org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException. I tried this earler and it seemed like gradle overrode my exception handling. No longer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Gradle behavior when a task is failing is to stop this task and then either fail the whole build or continue, in case the command line option `--continue` was provided (documentation **[here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html)**).

If you'd like to have javaexec executed for each file separately so if one execution fails the other will try to execute as well then you'll have to define different task dynamically for each execution, probably using **[task rules](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N10F07)**.

Now, regarding your following comment:

> `generateReportFromJson()` never gets called if there's a single scenario failing.

Then `generateReportFromJson()` is outside the `doLast` block. This means that it will get called during gradle configuration phase, i.e. before `javaexec` will be called so I'm not sure that it is related to the task failure thing.
However to make `generateReportFromJson()` called after task `runFeatures` you can simply move it to a separate task, and then either make it dependent on `runFeatures` in case you're using the `--continue` option and would like the whole build to continue or alternatively define the new task as a **[finalizer task](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N10F3E)** the thw  and execute the new task instead of `runFeatures`.

Comment: Regarding generateReportFromJson() being outside doLast: my bad Amnon, thanks. This was a digest of my code for clarity-- the live code doesn't make this mistake. Corrected in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I don't know if I made a mistake earlier, but it seems the behaviour has changed and the latest Gradle (2.3.7) lets you catch execException and handle it. Problem solved.